# How to connect to internet after removing Network Manager?

Tags: networking, package-management

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I deleted network manager and do not see both wireless and LAN connection icons in the desktop, and for this reason I cannot connect to the internet.
Any idea?

Comment: does `/etc/init.d/networking restart` through errors?

Answer (score 2):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Amend the file to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Proofread, save and close gedit. Now do:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

Your ethernet should now be connected so that you can re-install NM or Wicd. After doing so, repeat the process but remove the eth0 lines if you select NM. I believe the eth0 lines may remain for Wicd.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete Network Manager you have to configure all network settings manual. This is a bunch of work. However, it's possible.

Why do you have removed it? It is very convenient and I think you could configure all thinks you need.

A good advice for the manual network configuration you can find here: [Network Configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I delete network manager I can put an UTP cable in my system directly into my router. A reboot (or a `/etc/init.d/networking restart`) resets the networking and also shows me my LAN connection (though not with icons on the desktop it does work).

After that you can re-install network-manager (or wicd as that was the one I started using for a little while) over the wired connection.